# Value of _ (underscore) variable changes unexpectedly in Python interpreter

Tags: python, metaprogramming, magic-methods

I'm trying to create a module in Python that allows me to write a valid sentence like `map(_ + 2, range(10))`, just for fun, but there's a weird behavior I don't know how to deal with. My current implementation is:

```
class EasyLambda(object):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return lambda val: val + other

_ = EasyLambda()
```

Each operator has its own function like that. This is the dumb implementation, I'll improve it later to make things like `_.lower() + '.html'` possible. The problem is, everytime I call a magic method, Python seems to replace self by the new returned value, which is a lambda in this case.

```
>>> from mymodule import _
>>> print _
<func.EasyLambda object at 0x2e4ae90>

>>> add2 = _ + 2
>>> print add2, _
<function <lambda> at 0x2e551b8> <func.EasyLambda object at 0x2e13e90>

>>> add2(4)
6

>>> print add2, _
<function <lambda> at 0x2e551b8> 6    # WTF?

>>> print _, type(_)
6 <type 'int'>

>>> _ + 4
10

>>> _
10    # WTF??

>>> 2 + 2
4

>>> _
6    # WTF???
```

I have no idea what's going on here, really. How can I solve this problem and make my `_ object` behave as expected?

Comment: Inside the shell, `_` is used to store the last evaluated result..... Don't do anything with your `_` - just put `2 + 2` in IDLE/interactive prompt, then type `_` - you'll get 4

Comment: Dear lord --' I'll test again and edit my test

Comment: Outside of an interactive shell, it's generally used as a shorcut name for ugettext and localisation... I think the simplest thing is to avoid using that name to start with :)

Comment: It's not meant for serious use, just for fun, but thank you for the advice =D

Comment: Ok, I'm kinda embarrassed =S Could you put this on an answer, @JonClements, to close this question as fast as possible?

Comment: Okay - I've done so... have fun with your project...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_` is used by the interactive interpreter to store the last evaluated result. Everytime you're trying to do something, you're inadvertently having your `_` over-written. Also note that `_` is quite often used as a shortcut for `uggettext` and similar. Simplest solution is to avoid `_` for now...

Thanks to [thefourtheye](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) for pointing out the relevant section from the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) which states:

> The special identifier _ is used in the interactive interpreter to store the result of the last evaluation; it is stored in the `__builtin__` module. When not in interactive mode, `_` has no special meaning and is not defined. See section The import statement.
>
> Note The name `_` is often used in conjunction with internationalization; refer to the documentation for the `gettext` module for more information on this convention.